# Change font size of \cite without affecting \textcite

Tags: biblatex, fontsize, biber

I use the following command to reduce the font size of the citation number between brackets when using `\cite` in the text:

```
\renewcommand*{\citesetup}{%
  \biburlsetup
  \tiny
\frenchspacing
}
```

which indeed makes citations like [1] smaller when I use `\cite`.

However, when I use `\textcite`, e.g. *A. Uthor [1] says hi.*, it also makes the author name smaller which looks weird in the rest of the sentence. How can I keep `\normalsize` for A. Uthor, and `\small` for [1] when using `\textcite`?

FYI, I use biblatex with biber and natbib:

```
\usepackage[
  autocite     = plain,
  backend      = biber,
  style        = alphabetic,
  natbib       = true,   
  ]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit fiddly, since the bracketed citation label is typeset by different bits of the citation commands (in particular the brackets are produced by different macros), all of which need to be adapted.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, autocite=plain,]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\mkbibsmallbrackets}[1]{%
  {\small\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibsmallbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibsmallbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{small}{\small#1}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{namelabeldelim}%
       \small\bibopenbracket}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \printtext[small]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\small\bibclosebracket
       \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}
    {\setunit{}%
     \printtext{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\small\bibclosebracket
          \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}}}
    {\setunit{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\small\bibclosebracket
          \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}%
       \textcitedelim}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [SR98] ipsum Sigfridsson and Ryde [SR98]]